# How to send an approval or rejection email to workflow initiator in AEM workflow?

Tags: workflow, aem

I wanted to create a workflow, which sends an approval or rejection email to workflow initiator with approver comments.

Comment: Custom Workflow Process can be used to handle notifications which are not handled by AEM OOTB Notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your custom workflow process for the email notification. In that class you can than read the workflow initiator from the workflow instance model. This data is saved under the meta data node in the userid property.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Authorizable;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;

import com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkItem;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.metadata.MetaDataMap;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGateway;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGatewayService;

@Service
@Component(immediate = true)
public final class NotificationWorkflowProcess implements WorkflowProcess {

    @Reference
    private MessageGatewayService messageService;

    @Override
    public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaDataMap) throws WorkflowException {
        ResourceResolver resolver = workflowSession.adaptTo(ResourceResolver.class); // or get admin resolver here
        UserManager userManager = resolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);

        MessageGateway<HtmlEmail> messageGateway = messageService.getGateway(HtmlEmail.class);
        try {
            String initiator = workItem.getWorkflow().getInitiator();
            Authorizable authorizable = userManager.getAuthorizable(initiator);
            String userEmail = PropertiesUtil.toString(authorizable.getProperty("profile/email"), "");
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(userEmail)) {
                return;
            }
            HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
            email.setCharset(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
            email.addTo(userEmail);
            email.setSubject("test email subject");
            email.setMsg("text email body");
            email.setHtmlMsg("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>html email body</p></body></html>");
            messageGateway.send(email);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // cannot send email. print some error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```